# Terminate a process by Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, process, terminate

If I terminate myself, just use the `[NSApp terminate: nil]`, it works very well. But if I want to terminate another process such as the active monitor, what should I do?

To get the list of processes, I use

```
NSArray* processlist = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
```

Am I right? But how I can terminate a process by Cocoa, not use the `kill` or `KillProcess(<#const ProcessSerialNumber *inProcess#>)` or `killpd` or something like those, I just start learning Cocoa, so maybe I need some simple sample code or some keywords that can help me to find the documents. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6):

`-[NSWorkspace runningApplications]` returns an array of `NSRunningApplication` objects.  `NSRunningApplication` has a method `-[NSRunningApplication terminate]`. So if you are looking for a specific application, you could terminate it like this:

```
-(void)killProcessesNamed:(NSString*)appName
{
    for ( id app in [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications] ) 
    {
        if ( [appName isEqualToString:[[app executableURL] lastPathComponent]] ) 
        {
            [app terminate];
        }
    }
}
```

You could also call `forceTerminate` to force the app to quit without the normal quitting process. (It won't ask to save changes, etc.)

There are other methods of `NSRunningApplication` that you can use to make this process simpler depending on whether or not you're searching for a process based on bundle ID or PID.

Comment: A minor niggle, but isn't 
`if ( [appName isEqualToString:[[app executableURL] lastPathComponent]] == YES )`
equivalent to
`if ( [appName isEqualToString:[[app executableURL] lastPathComponent]])`
?

Comment: Um yes, it will do the same exact same thing obviously.

Comment: thank you very much.And I see it [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSRunningApplication)at that page, and I am not sure why I can not rely on this for comparing processes, and if there are some process with the same name running in the workspace, how should I do?

Comment: The code I posted will kill all processes with that name. If you want to get a list of apps by bundle ID, you can use +[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:], or if you know the PID, you can use +[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:].

Comment: It says not to rely on the processIdentifier call to compare two NSRunningApplication objects because "Not all applications have a pid.".  Instead it says to use isEqual:

Comment: This answers almost perfectly my question, thanks for the great answer! One question I have though is, how do I determine the `executableURL` of the app whose process I want to kill?