# Can you close a separate application from one you make in Xcode OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode6

Is there any way to close a application from one that you make in Xcode for Mac like have it so if iTunes is running it will see that it is and close it for you.

Comment: Why, yes it is possible. And if you read [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/index.html) or [searched this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175585/terminate-a-process-by-cocoa) you'd even know how to do it.

Comment: Yes there is a way to do that.

Comment: @SevenBits you are correct, but be nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

First off, Stack Overflow is not a site where you can ask open-ended questions like this one. You are expected to read the documentation first and tell us **what you have tried** before you post a question. In your case, reading Apple's documentation or doing an Internet search would have revealed the answer (I found it in about 5 seconds) which you could have tried and, if after trying different solutions, it *still* doesn't work, then you can post here.

With that out of the way, here's the answer to your question:

The `NSRunningApplication` class has a method named `terminate` which terminates the process that it corresponds to. So, you just create an instance of that class and call the `terminate` method. For example:

```
BOOL terminated = [[[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Safari"] objectAtIndex:0] terminate];
NSLog(@"Termination successful? %@", terminated ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Hope this helps.